# Capacitive touch on a pcb

Tags: capacitor, pcb

Using a dedicated functionality on a processor, I know how to detect touch on a metal pad.

My question is doing it on a pcb in a nice looking way.

1. I could just expose few large pads (which are metals) and connect them to ports on the processor, it's nice but I want something else.
2. Can I put the pads on the **bottom** of the pcb, and draw the buttons right on the **top** of it so I can sense without touching directly on the exposed pads ?

**My concern** is that if it works with a single button, then I will not be able to **differentiate** between multiple because the board is a **uniform** shape, and if I touch on point A it's like B in terms of capacitance ? ( or at least almost identical because of the **noise**. )

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell without knowing what the "dedicated functionality on a processor" does - for **capacitive** touch sensing, the touched surfaces should typically be non-conductive (i.e. **not** exposed copper pads) but isolated.

Comment: Thanks can you explain why should they be isolated ? if I take out a wire from the processor and touch it, it works, so my logic says I should just expose a pad on the pcb, no ?

Comment: because *capacitive* implies exactly that: isolated.

Comment: So how is it working when I just connect exposed wire to the processor, and NOT working if it's a wood ? isn't that means that it should be an exposed metal?

Comment: no. You need a large isolated surface to have a large *capacity* between finger and pin. The thickness of the isolating layer between finger and metal surface also, reducingly, influences that capacity

Comment: I'd really recommend reading the *Capacitive Sensing* wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_sensing).

Comment: I'v actually read about it, and I think I know what a capacitor is, but you still do not have a direct answer to this question, how is it works with an EXPOSED piece of wire ( a wire that close a circuit), there is no isolation, and you simply measure capacitance on it's edge?

Comment: Having an exposed conductor for people to touch shorted to a processor pin sounds like a good way to break the pin and or processor.

Comment: well, unlike with the usual, safe, capacitive sensing, your body becomes part of the driven electrode, and your capacity to ground, together with the capacity from ground to device, becomes the secondary side. That's a) a great way to kill your device if you're at a different potential, b) a great way of having something that works sometimes and sometimes not, depending on humidity, skin resistance, shoes, the place where people stand, RF interference, … So, that's why you *never do that*.

Comment: Watch your language! You came here looking for help, not an argument. If you treat our volunteers with respect, you'll get the information you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a multilayer PCB, you could place 2 Pads on the most bottom and the second most bottom layer. If you connect them to an OPamp, you should be able to detect changes in the charge distribution on the pads. Since nobody is really neutral/chargeless, a person touching the "painted" pad on the influences the two pads differently, which causes a peak at the output of the OPamp. Using a lowpass on its output and maybe using a schmitt-trigger before processing the signal. Since the Coulomb-potential scales with 1 over r^2 the potential diffenrence between the two pads should not be that much, that it works from far away, also you may scale it yourself, hence you should even be able to place multiple "buttons" on a single pcb.